# How best to segment users into 'favourite categories' based on subjective on-site behaviour in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site with ~10 topics (and multiple pages, sections, tools, experiences etc. that are tracked via events & pages, also categorised within those topics).

I want to segment my users into ~10 different segments, based on the topic that they are 'most engaged with' or 'most interested in'.

The issue is, I cannot set an objective cutoff behaviour that can be used to determine someone 'engaged' with a topic, because engagement levels vary wildly across users (for example, heavy users engage with multiple topics, a lot, but typically have one 'favourite' topic that they engage with much more, whereas light users engage with multiple topics, a small amount, and have one 'favourite' topic that they engage with more, but not necessarily a lot relative to heavy users).
This means that objective conditions that would normally be used for segmentation, such as *'if user triggers 10 events within this topic, they are engaged/interested'* will not work (because all heavy users would meet this condition and therefore be assigned multiple 'favourite topics', which is undesirable).

I instead want to be able to assign users a 'favourite' topic, which would be the topic that they trigger the most events/visit the most pages of. I can then use their total engagement to create a segmentation matrix of 'favourite topic' and 'light to medium to heavy user', which I can then use to deliver different experiences, uncover insight, etc.

How might I go about doing this via Google Analytics?